# Do I need a new visa for Russia if my name has been legally changed?

Tags: visas, russia

I am a U.S. passport holder and have a three-year-multiple-entry tourist visa for Russia which is still valid.

My first name was legally changed, and I have a new passport issued in that name as well as the court order. The visa is in my old/cancelled passport.

Must I apply for a new visa or may I travel to and from Russia using the still-valid visa in my old passport?

Answer (score 4):

I can't find any reference to it at the moment, but to the best of my knowledge, the visa is still valid. I know this from a friend who's been in exactly this situation (name change after marriage). When you travel, you need to have with you:

- Your old (no longer valid) passport with the (still valid) visa in your old name
- Court document confirming your name change
- Notarised translation of this court document into Russian (this may not be strictly needed, but better have it)
- Your new passport into your new name

If you are still unsure, I suggest you contact Russian Consulate section or a visa agency.  If you're in the USA, the phone number of the Russian Consulate visa section in New York is (212) 348-5762.  Alternatively the Consulate recommends using an agency called Russian Visa Centre.  The phone numbers of that agency are (212) 430-59-90 (in New York) or (202) 827-0880 (in Washington). It won't hurt giving them a call.